# ruby on rails button_to or ideally f.button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button

I'm working on a 'Log In' / 'Sign Up ' form, a project I've 'inherited' from someone else. My Rails isn't that advanced but I'm enjoying it, apart from frustrations of getting something tiny to work in about 10 hours.

When people want to log in, after entering their username and password, they click a 'Log in' button, which works fine:

```
<%= f.button :submit, I18n.t('sign_in.sign_in_button'), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Now, how can I create a Sign Up button that directs the user to the 'Create account' page?

For example, this link works perfectly:

```
<%= link_to I18n.t('sign_in.sign_up'), new_user_registration_path %>
```

`new_user_registration_path` goes to the 'Create account' page. Is there nowhere I can stick `new_user_registration_path` within my button code?

I tried this too, put when clicked it just keeps refreshing the current page, rather than going to the 'Create Account' page:

```
<%= button_to I18n.t('sign_in.sign_up_button'), new_user_registration_path, :class => 'btn btn-warning' %>
```

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to  
this method creates a form tag.

Are you maybe using this within a form?  a form within a form won't act as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap. This is the perfect use case for a link as you have, but styled as a button. Try:
`<%= link_to I18n.t('sign_in.sign_up'), new_user_registration_path, :class => "btn btn-warning" %>`

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for help. Bootstrap sounds familiar alright.I thought I'd tried every possible combination of things within the button...yours worked perfect.